tcl scrollbar no more works when I remove the frames inside the canva that has the scrollbar
I use the following code to have a scrollbar that works great :
(thanks : How to add a scrollbar to tcl frame)
ttk::frame .frAlles

# create canvas with scrollbars
canvas .frAlles.c -width 400 -height 200 -xscrollcommand ".frAlles.xscroll set" -yscrollcommand ".frAlles.yscroll set"
ttk::scrollbar .frAlles.xscroll -orient horizontal -command ".frAlles.c xview"
ttk::scrollbar .frAlles.yscroll -command ".frAlles.c yview"
pack .frAlles.xscroll -side bottom -fill x
pack .frAlles.yscroll -side right -fill y
pack .frAlles.c -expand yes -fill both -side top

# create frame with widgets
ttk::frame .frAlles.c.frWidgets -borderwidth 1 -relief solid -width 340 -height 700

for {set i 0} {$i <=20} {incr i} {
  ttk::label .frAlles.c.frWidgets.lb$i -text "Label $i:"
  ttk::entry .frAlles.c.frWidgets.en$i
  ttk::button .frAlles.c.frWidgets.bt$i -text "Button $i" -command exit
  grid .frAlles.c.frWidgets.lb$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 0
  grid .frAlles.c.frWidgets.en$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 1
  grid .frAlles.c.frWidgets.bt$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 2 
}

# create frame with buttons
ttk::frame .frAlles.c.frButtons -borderwidth 1 -relief solid -width 340 -height 40
ttk::button .frAlles.c.frButtons.btOK -text "OK" -command exit
ttk::button .frAlles.c.frButtons.btAbbruch -text "Abbruch" -command exit
pack .frAlles.c.frButtons.btOK -padx 2 -pady 2 -side left
pack .frAlles.c.frButtons.btAbbruch -padx 2 -pady 2 -side left

# place widgets and buttons
.frAlles.c create window 0 0 -anchor nw -window .frAlles.c.frWidgets 
.frAlles.c create window 200 650 -anchor c -window .frAlles.c.frButtons 

# determine the scrollregion
.frAlles.c configure -scrollregion [.frAlles.c bbox all]

# show the canvas
pack .frAlles -expand yes -fill both -side top

But if I remove the frames inside the canva so that I have widget directly inside the canva, then the scroling no more works : I have the scrolling bar but they have no effect.
do you know why ?
Here is the code modified, without the frames frWidgets and frButtons. I removed the frames because the first frame contain a huge number of checkbutton widget and then I can't do the create window command for the second frame as the first one will be very long. for instance if the loop is not 20 but 200, then the button will be displayed in front of the list and the scrollbar won't display the complete list. It act as if the scrollbar is usefull only to display the two frames but not the totality of the first frame. (hard to explain but the code can be executed inside a wish command easily)
ttk::frame .frAlles

# create canvas with scrollbars
canvas .frAlles.c -width 400 -height 200 -xscrollcommand ".frAlles.xscroll set" -yscrollcommand ".frAlles.yscroll set"
ttk::scrollbar .frAlles.xscroll -orient horizontal -command ".frAlles.c xview"
ttk::scrollbar .frAlles.yscroll -command ".frAlles.c yview"
pack .frAlles.xscroll -side bottom -fill x
pack .frAlles.yscroll -side right -fill y
pack .frAlles.c -expand yes -fill both -side top

# create frame with widgets

for {set i 0} {$i <=20} {incr i} {
  ttk::label .frAlles.c.lb$i -text "Label $i:"
  ttk::entry .frAlles.c.en$i
  ttk::button .frAlles.c.bt$i -text "Button $i" -command exit
  grid .frAlles.c.lb$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 0
  grid .frAlles.c.en$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 1
  grid .frAlles.c.bt$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 2 
}


ttk::button .frAlles.c.btOK -text "OK" -command exit
ttk::button .frAlles.c.btAbbruch -text "Abbruch" -command exit
pack .frAlles.c.btOK -padx 2 -pady 2 -side left
pack .frAlles.c.btAbbruch -padx 2 -pady 2 -side left


# determine the scrollregion
.frAlles.c configure -scrollregion [.frAlles.c bbox all]

# show the canvas
pack .frAlles -expand yes -fill both -side top

I also tried this little code that create a canva with a line and inside the canva there are a lot of checkbutton. the scrolling is working only for the canva and the line but not for the button that are inside the canva :-(
 package require Tk

 proc scrolled w {
    set pa [set pa0 [winfo parent $w]]
    if {$pa eq "."} {set pa ""}
    grid $w [scrollbar $pa.y -command "$w yview"] -sticky news
    $w configure -xscrollcommand "$pa.x set" -yscrollcommand "$pa.y set"
    grid $pa.y -sticky ns
    grid [scrollbar $pa.x -ori hori -command "$w xview"] -sticky ew
    grid columnconfigure $pa0 0 -weight 1
    grid rowconfigure    $pa0 0 -weight 1
    
    for {set i 0} {$i <=200} {incr i} {
        ttk::label .c.lb$i -text "Label $i:"
        ttk::entry .c.en$i
        ttk::button .c.bt$i -text "Button $i" -command exit
        grid .c.lb$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 0
        grid .c.en$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 1
        grid .c.bt$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 2
    } 
 }
 canvas .c -background beige 
 .c create line 10 10 10000 10000
 .c configure -scrollregion [.c bbox all]
 scrolled .c


I tried your last example and see your problem. But the way you are doing it does not work. A canvas is a drawing element that does not hold widgets the same way as a frame would do. So using pack or grid does not work. By the way, you should not mix pack and grid inside the same element.
They way you could solve your problem is by using Window Items:
<canvas> create window x y ?option value ...?

Or get rid of the canvas ...

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/A+scrolled+frame
might help as well.
There, Paul Walton's implementation of the scrolled frame is one of the best and might present ideas for you.
